# How To Add Parent Category And Child Category in same Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have One Dropdownlist

table name= Parent_Category 
table name= Child Category

I want bind like this

Electronic ----Parent Category
 Mobile--------Child Category

in one dropdownlist

Comment: shed some more light please .

Comment: Bad explain, tell more plz

Comment: Show your code what you have did.